# Vector multiplication in BUGS and JAGS

Tags: bugs, jags

In R, c(3,1,0) * c(2,0,1) == c(6,0,0). This is not dot product and it's not cross product. First, what is the name for this product, and second, does it work in WinBUGS, OpenBUGS and/or JAGS?

Comment: this is just element-wise multiplication. i'm not sure if it works in WinBUGS, OpenBUGS, or JAGS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike JAGS, WinBUGS and OpenBUGS does not do this form of vectorization; you *have* to write a loop, and compute each element 'by hand', as described above.

Answer (score 7):

Martyn Plummer points out that this is implemented in JAGS, which I missed when reading the manual. From Ch 5:

> Scalar functions taking scalar arguments are automatically vectorized.
>   They can also be called when the arguments are arrays with conforming
>   dimensions, or scalars. So, for example, the scalar $c$ can be added
>   to the matrix $A$ using
>
> ```
> B <- A + c
> ```
>
> instead of the more verbose form
>
> ```
> D <- dim(A)
> for (i in 1:D[1])
>   for (j in 1:D[2]) {
>     B[i,j] <- A[i,j] + c
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

To do element-wise multiplication you can just make a for loop in those languages and that's it! I've used for loops in WinBUGS with no problems.

Comment: What question does this reply address?  It does not seem to be relevant here.

Comment: @whubber, why? It is perfectly relevant. Ok, I changed the post a little to be more clear.

Comment: Yup, a for loop is what I've been doing so far; I'd just wondered if a vectorized version was possible.

Comment: I've submitted a feature request to JAGS: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3470513&group_id=176821&atid=878777

Comment: Thanks, Tomas.  Now I see the connection: you're not answering the question as stated, but you are offering a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally, element-wise multiplication of two equal length vectors is called the Hadamard product (aka the Schur product).